# How to check if the value of a variable in a loop is equal to the previous value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

If I have a function that runs a Python loop:

```
def read_progress():
    while True:
        with open('progress.txt', 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            time = lines[-5].split('=')[-1].split('.')[0]
            time.sleep(1)
```

How do I check if `time` is the same as what it was last time and break out of the loop (or make the function do nothing) if this is the case?

I was thinking something like:

```
def read_progress():
    previous_time = '00:00:00'
    while True:
        if previous_time == time:
            break
        with open('progress.txt', 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            time = lines[-5].split('=')[-1].split('.')[0]
            time.sleep(1)
            previous_time = time
```

But won't `if previous_time == time` always be true because I'm making `previous_time` equal to `time`? I can find things like this hard to wrap my head around, so I would greatly appreciate it if someone could edit the code if it's wrong so that I can achieve what I want :)

Comment: sounds like you need a second variable that stores time_previous or have the time variable store a tuple where one is the current and the other is the previous.  Need to store the previous time somewhere in order to compare it.

Comment: Do not name a variable `time` since it shadows the built-in; `time.sleep(1)` will fail.

Comment: @Mike I've edited the question to show an idea that I had but I don't think it will work due to the reason I gave. Finding it hard to wrap my head around how to do this. If you could write the code that will allow me to achieve this, I will appreciate it :)

Comment: Your idea will work but the `if` statement needs to come after the line that sets the `time` to something new and before the line that sets `previous_time = time`

Comment: @Stuart that makes sense! Thanks Stuart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As corrected by @Stuart, the if-statement needs to be moved. Here's the solution:

```
def read_progress():
    previous_time = '00:00:00'
    while True:
        with open('progress.txt', 'r') as f:

            lines = f.readlines()
            current_time = lines[-5].split('=')[-1].split('.')[0]

            if previous_time == current_time:
                break

            previous_time = current_time

            time.sleep(1)
```